# HotChocolate Authorization exception on test project

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm getting the following error message when testing queries on a test project:

"The feature Authorization is missing the state with the key HotChocolate.Authorization.UserState"

My TestExecutorHelper has the .AddAuthorization() and .AddAuthorizationPermissions() it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how i can solve this?

Here's my TestExecutor.ExecuteAsync method

```
IRequestExecutorBuilder requestExecutor = serviceCollection
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddGraphQL()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddAuthorizePermissions()
            .AddErrorFilter<ErrorFilter>()
            .AddQueryType<QueryType>();
var serviceProvider = requestExecutor.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var request = QueryRequestBuilder.New()
            .SetQuery(query)
            .SetServices(serviceProvider)
            .Create();
var executor = await requestExecutor.BuildRequestExecutorAsync();
return await executor.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you have this problem because of calling `.AddGraphQL()` instead of `.AddGraphQLServer()`.

State `UserState` is added inside [DefaultHttpRequestInterceptor](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/blob/ff14574a846785f28f2425a0cadcff78122e9173/src/HotChocolate/AspNetCore/src/AspNetCore/DefaultHttpRequestInterceptor.cs#L25), and `DefaultHttpRequestInterceptor` is registered inside [AddGraphQLServer](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/blob/ff14574a846785f28f2425a0cadcff78122e9173/src/HotChocolate/AspNetCore/src/AspNetCore/Extensions/HotChocolateAspNetCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L107), but not in [AddGraphQL](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/blob/ff14574a846785f28f2425a0cadcff78122e9173/src/HotChocolate/Core/src/Execution/DependencyInjection/RequestExecutorServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L113)

Comment: Thanks, but it wasn't it, it turns out the issue was the DefaultAuthorizationHandler, in the GetUserState method, due to it being a test project there wasn't a user or claimsprincipal available so it always throws an exception, I solved it by making a custom AuthorizationHandler that adds a claimsprincipal